# Left-continuous version of right-continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f^+$ be a real-valued cádlág function defined on the real line, i.e.,

- the left-limit $\lim_{x\uparrow t}f^+(x)$ exists for each $t$, and
- the right-limit $\lim_{x\downarrow t}f^+(x)$ exists and equals $f^+(t)$ for each $t$.

How is the left-continuous version $(f^+)^-$ of $f^+$ defined? In particular, let $f^-$ denote a cáglád function such that $f^-$ equals to $f^+$ on all continuity points of $f^+$, i.e.,

- the left-limit $\lim_{x\uparrow t}f^-(x)$ exists and equals $f^-(t)$ for each $t$,
- the right-limit $\lim_{x\downarrow t}f^-(x)$ exists for each $t$, and
- $f^-(c) = f^+$ for all $c$, where $f^+(c)$ is continuous.

Does it hold that $(f^+)^- = f^-$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left continuous version of any function $h$ having left limits is defined by
$$
h^-(x)=\lim_{t\uparrow x}h(t)\,.
$$
In particular this applies to your cádlág function $f^+\,.$
To use less confusing superscripts I denote this function by $h$ and
the special cáglád function $f^-$ you defined in those three
bullet points by $f\,.$

In short: $f$ is defined as being cáglád and being identical to
$h$ in all points where $h$ is continuous.

Since in those points $h^-=h$ it follows that $h^-=f$ holds wherever
$h$ is continuous.

Your question then boils down to: Does $h^-=f$ still hold where $h$ is not continuous?

To prove this it helps to use the fact that [every
cádlág function can have only countably many points of discontinuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502162/cardinality-of-set-of-discontinuities-of-cadlag-functions). Therefore,
when $h$ is not continuous at $c$
we can find a sequence $x_n\uparrow c$ such that $h$ is continuous
at every $x_n\,.$ Since $h^-$ and $f$ are both left continuous it follows
from
$$
h^-(x_n)=h(x_n)\stackrel{\text{3rd. bullet point}}{=}f(x_n)
$$
that $h^-(c)=f(c)\,.$

Comment: very clean answer, thank you! I just wonder why I did not see it. It's quite straightforward, isn't it?

Comment: It was not straightforward for me in the beginning. The 3rd. bullet point is crucial. It looks like we have shown the nice Lemma that for any cádlág function $h\,,$ its left continuous version $h^-$ is cáglád. (Since it agrees with $f$.)